# Property 'src' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339) and Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have been playing around with these codes and I still keep getting errors.

```
const zoom = () => {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll(".voice-details__zoom");
  const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
  const modalImg = document.querySelector(".modalImg");
  const modalTxt = document.querySelector(".modalTxt");
  const close = document.querySelector(".close");

  images.forEach((image) => {
    image.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let imgSrc = image.getAttribute('data-src');
      modalImg.src = imgSrc; //2 errors
      modalTxt.innerHTML = image.getAttribute('data-alt'); //2 errors
      modal?.classList.add("appear");

      close?.addEventListener("click", () => {
        modal?.classList.remove("appear");
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Here are the errors from the compiler:
10:06:36 AM - File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
[watch:ts]
[watch:ts] src/js/components/zoom.ts(15,7): error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
[watch:ts] src/js/components/zoom.ts(15,16): error TS2339: Property 'src' does not exist on type 'Element'.
[watch:ts] src/js/components/zoom.ts(16,7): error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
[watch:ts] src/js/components/zoom.ts(16,7): error TS2322: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
[watch:ts]   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go over and fix the errors one by one.

> src/js/components/zoom.ts(15,7): error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

The error is complaining that `modalImg` could possibly be `null` if the `querySelector(".modalImg")` call fails to find a matching element. So, to fix this error we should assign the attribute if and only if `modalImg` is found.

```
if (modalImg) modalImg.src = imgSrc;
```

> src/js/components/zoom.ts(15,16): error TS2339: Property 'src' does not exist on type 'Element'.

In addition to the *null check*, a *typecast* is required here since `src` is not a property of `Element`, but of the subtype  `HTMLImageElement`.

```
if (modalImg) {
    (<HTMLImageElement>modalImg).src = imgSrc;
}
```

> src/js/components/zoom.ts(16,7): error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

A *null check* is required for `modalTxt` too.

```
if (modalTxt) modalTxt.innerHTML = ... ;
```

> src/js/components/zoom.ts(16,7): error TS2322: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'

The error is complaining that `image.getAttribute('data-alt')` could possibly be `null` and, hence, cannot be assigned to the `innerHTML` *string* property. So, to fix this error we can either use *OR* `||` or the *nullish coalescing* `??` operator.

```
if (modalTxt) {
    modalTxt.innerHTML = image.getAttribute('data-alt') ?? "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this, Last question, how could I remove the new errors?
I followed the code but I got 2 errors ->  The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.ts(2779)

Comment: @KirbyTan Please check my update, it should work without errors now.